# Algorithm to detect outliers in network sensor messages

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a network sensor device which generates a number of messages. The message is of format "timeofmessage messagetype messageimportance messagetext". The sensor keeps producing "sensor-ok" messages periodically(every 10 minutes) and couple of other messages at regular intervals. These are just log messages which says the sensor is up and working fine. The sensor also produces messages with different messagetypes and messageimportance when there is a problem with it. I consider these messages which are produced when there is a problem as outliers. What is the best machine learning algorithm to detect outliers from such data? Are clustering algorithms good for this case?

Comment: Why do you need machine learning in here? Isn't it a problem that needs an if-else expression and a list of all the possible message types that is presumably fixed?

Comment: I do not have list of all possible messagetype or text. Also if I have to support a new type of sensor in the future then the solution has to be as generic as possible. Also consider different sensor vendors have different message formats. I would rather spend time on preparing the data and feed it to common solution than to edit if-else everytime

Comment: Don't you have a list of the messages that are _not_ unusual? I gather anything else would be the "outliers".